# TF255440 error on configuring TFS 2010 upgrade from RC to RTM

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I'm running the tfs upgrade wizard (from RC to RTM). On reaching the Readiness Checks I'm getting an error on the 'Configuration Database' :

[ Configuration Database ] TF255440: The following account has a SQL Server login, but the login was denied access: DOMAIN\User. The server selected to host the databases for Team Foundation Server is: MYSERVER. The SQL Server login associated with the user account must be granted access to the SQL Server instance on that server.

I've tried changing user mappings and roles but so far no joy.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error.  In a last ditch effort, I deleted my Windows account from the SQL Logins to see if it would at least report a different error. To my surprise, it instead worked. I can still connect to SQL Server with my Windows Account because Domain Admins is listed as a SQL Server login and I am a member of that group. So perhaps the verification logic is flawed when there is more than one way for an account to authenticate to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Chance for the Wonderful post.

Even I was getting the same error while configuring the Team foundation Server. (SQL Server login, but the login was denied access: )

Delete the Login Account from the Security -> Login -> Your Account Name
It works